# Any tool for forking/teeing/sharing a TCP connection to the remote server?

Tags: networking, tcp

*Could down voter please post your reason, as it's not obvious to me?*

Here's my problem. I'm building an automation program that talks to a remote server (think of it as a chat server or MUD game server) through TCP. While my automation program is doing its thing, I want to connect to the server using the regular client for that service.

Functionally, this requires some "tee" or "mulplexer", or "proxy" on my local machine. It connects to the remote server. And the two local clients connect to it via TCP. It needs to forward any incoming data from the remote server to ALL the local clients. It also needs to forward any outgoing data from ANY of the clients to the remote server.

I don't concern the outbound traffic from different clients to be interleaved, as the outbound traffic (client -> server) is spontaneous and it's not likely to have multiple clients to send at the same time.

Is there such a tool? Visually, this is what I need:

[image]

## Update

In realizing that it maybe difficult to find an existing solution for my scenario. I built one that allows multiple TCP clients to share a single TCP connection to a server. Traffic generated by the server is forwarded to all clients. Traffic generated from any client is forwarded to the server. I host it [here](https://github.com/kflu/multiplexer) in case someone need it too and/or want to make contribution.

How is it useful? In many cases, we want to write program to automate tasks with a remote service, but at the same time want to keep using the existing tool that doesn't offer the functionality that your automation program is capable of, but provides an easy/familiar UI, so that your automation program won't have to.

### Usage

1. Start the multiplexer from command line
2. Connect clients to localhost:3333
3. In multiplxer command line, input command `connect <server> <port>` to connect to the remote service that will be shared by all the clients.
4. At any time, you can terminate a client, or connect a new client, without affecting the connection to the remote server.

Here's a demonstration of it in action. As an example, in this case, there're two MUD clients sharing the same connection to the server. Imagine one of the two clients is a thin program that automates your player, but provides no ability for human intervention. And the other client is a regular feature-rich MUD client that you can interact with.

[image]

Comment: Look up multicast and or anycast

Comment: Any down vote please comment on the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just code what you need. Something pre-built won't work because you need to identify message boundaries. Otherwise, messages may get interleaved, causing the server to be unable to understand them.

Comment: Thanks. In my scenario, the traffic is spontaneous and it's not likely that multiple clients will send at the same time. And if that happens, it's affordable to repeat what just sent. But I guess that's still domain specific. So there's no existing tool like that?

Comment: I don't think so. But you could try adapting [a tool](https://github.com/agnoster/duplicator) that almost does what you want.